# OnScaleGestureListener - when zoomed in and when zoomed out

Tags: java, android

According to the documentation `OnScaleGestureListener` have 3 method, `onScaleBegin`, `onScale` and `onScaleEnd`.
Somewhere on the internet I read that we can use `OnScaleGestureListener` to detect, when a user zooms in or reduces our view.
I want to display message by Toast, when someone touches the screen to zoomed view and when someone touches the screen to reduce the view.
I can't understand this doc about this methods, which method from this 3 method is used to detect zoom and which to detect zoom out ?

Answer (score 0):

They are not used for detecting zoom level, they are invoked when an user starts zooming, while zooming(in or out it does not matter) and when zoom ends in your condition. You detect zoom in or zoom out by comparing zoom level from onScaleBegin and onScaleEnd.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "and when zoom ends in your condition" ?